# How to send an email to user email account in android

Tags: android

4 Text-views and one button are present in my app screen.
how can i send the data present in that text-views as an email to user account.

Comment: See this link: http://lokeshatandroid.blogspot.in/2012/05/sending-email-in-android.html You can set your four textviews text like this: String message = tv1.gettext().toString()+ tv2.gettext().toString()+tv2.gettext().toString()+tv3.gettext().toString(); Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"youremail@yahoo.com"}); email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject"); email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message); email.setType("message/rfc822"); startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));

Comment: here user is already logged in with email,
so for that email i have to send the details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"myemail@xyz.com"});          
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "message");
    email.setType("message/rfc822");


try {
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
    } 
catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

For a detailed explnation, have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-send-email-in-android/).

Comment: after clicking on button instantly 4 textviews content should be send to user (user is already logged in )

Comment: You can get the text from the EditTexts when the button is clicked and send them in the putIntent() of the email intent.